# Any way to speed up Python and Pygame?

Tags: python, performance, pygame, frame-rate

I am writing a simple top down RPG in Pygame, and I have found that it is quite slow.... Although I am not expecting python or pygame to match the FPS of games made with compiled languages like C/C++ or even Byte Compiled ones like Java, but still the current FPS of pygame is like 15. I tried rendering 16-color Bitmaps instead of PNGs or 24 Bitmaps, which slightly boosted the speed, then in desperation, I switched everything to black and white monochrome bitmaps and that made the FPS go to 35. But not more. Now according to most game development books I have read, for a user to be completely satisfied with game graphics, the FPS of a 2d game should at least be 40, so is there ANY way of boosting the speed of pygame?

Comment: Have you profiled yet?

Comment: profiled yet? sorry i dont understand. plz explain what you are trying to say.

Comment: The problem most likely lies in your code (as in all projects). Profiling is the act of finding out where. Type "python profiling" in the search box [or go here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).

Comment: Everyone wants to teach how to write code, but no one wants to teach how to do it right :/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: I see. So if I code better , the performance of my game will be better. @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Yes, no tutorial ever mentioned this, all they teach is to do stuff and dont worry about the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: You have to profile the code. "Premature optimazation is the root of all evil". You can easily draw hundred full color png images at 60fps. So you don't need to optimize images. Use pngs, unless you are using images 3000,3000 pixels.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Psyco, for python2:

```
import psyco
psyco.full()
```

Also, enable doublebuffering. For example:

```
from pygame.locals import *
flags = FULLSCREEN | DOUBLEBUF
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, flags, bpp)
```

You could also turn off alpha if you don't need it:

```
screen.set_alpha(None)
```

Instead of flipping the entire screen every time, keep track of the changed areas and only update those. For example, something roughly like this (main loop):

```
events = pygame.events.get()
for event in events:
    # deal with events
pygame.event.pump()
my_sprites.do_stuff_every_loop()
rects = my_sprites.draw()
activerects = rects + oldrects
activerects = filter(bool, activerects)
pygame.display.update(activerects)
oldrects = rects[:]
for rect in rects:
    screen.blit(bgimg, rect, rect)
```

Most (all?) drawing functions return a rect.

You can also set only some allowed events, for more speedy event handling:

```
pygame.event.set_allowed([QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP])
```

Also, I would not bother with creating a buffer manually and would not use the HWACCEL flag, as I've experienced problems with it on some setups.

Using this, I've achieved reasonably good FPS and smoothness for a small 2d-platformer.

Comment: Thanks , the DOUBLEBUF flag gave me the final boost I needed for my 40 FPS goal. I will try rendering seperate rects but since all the sprites of my rpg are first blitted by the tile engine onto a huge surface and then that surface is blitted on the screen, it wont make a lot of difference. Thanks! I finally got the 40 FPS I wanted. ^_^

Comment: "all the sprites of my rpg are first blitted by the tile engine onto a huge surface and then that surface is blitted on the screen"

Yeah, that's a problem. You should only blit the things that need to be blitted - put bounding boxes around the sprites, and only blit the ones that actually touch the screen.

Comment: @quantumpotato over 30 FPS on a laptop that was already old in 2011, for a very simple platform game. It would be a lot faster on a modern computer, but it would all depend on the game, number of sprites, if the background is scrolling or not etc.

Comment: Thank you - I am exploring using a raspberry pi

Comment: I'm actually trying to improve my own performance using this Buffering technique. But I'm getting an error due to an undefined variable "bpp". What exactly is this supposed to be? I don't see it in your code like I do for flags.

Comment: Storm Claw, it's not a complete program, you need to fill in the blanks yourself. `bpp` is "bits per pixel" and is often 8, 16 or 24. For more information, check out the Pygame documentation, which is excellent.

Comment: psyco is unmaintained and not recommended as of 2012 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyco

Comment: Yes, now in 2021 I would rather go for SDL2 or GLFW together with either Nim, C++20, Go, Swift or Crystal. Or try something completely different like Godot.

Answer (score 6):

All of these are great suggestions and work well, but you should also keep in mind two things:

1) Blitting surfaces onto surfaces is faster than drawing directly. So pre-drawing fixed images onto surfaces (outside the main game loop), then blitting the surface to the main screen will be more efficient. For exmample:

```
# pre-draw image outside of main game loop
image_rect = get_image("filename").get_rect()
image_surface = pygame.Surface((image_rect.width, image_rect.height))
image_surface.blit(get_image("filename"), image_rect)
......
# inside main game loop - blit surface to surface (the main screen)
screen.blit(image_surface, image_rect)
```

2) Make sure you aren't wasting resources by drawing stuff the user can't see. for example:

```
if point.x >= 0 and point.x <= SCREEN_WIDTH and point.y >= 0 and point.y <= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
    # then draw your item
```

These are some general concepts that help me keep FPS high.

Comment: I think this is true, blit everything on a secundary surface and then blit this secondary surface in the main surface in the main loop. Another stuff I think is useful is to use sprite.Group() add all sprites to the group and then draw the grouped sprites all at once.

Answer (score 4):

When using images it is important to convert them with the convert()-function of the image.
I have read that convert() disables alpha which is normally quite slow.
I also had speed problems until I used a colour depth of 16 bit and the convert function for my images. Now my FPS are around 150 even if I blit a big image to the screen.

```
image = image.convert()#video system has to be initialed
```

Also rotations and scaling takes a lot of time to calculate. A big, transformed image can be saved in another image if it is immutable.

So the idea is to calculate once and reuse the outcome multiple times.

Comment: for others who might be having the same problem I did, removing alpha with convert() from the sprites didn't do anything for me, but I overlooked the background image. Removing the alpha from the background I was redrawing each time was HUGE performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

First, always use 'convert()' because it disables alpha which makes bliting faster.
Then only update the parts of the screen that need to be updated.

```
global rects

rects = []

rects.append(pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), (20, 20), (100, 400), 1)) 

pygame.display.update(rects) # pygame will only update those rects
```

Note:

When moving a sprite you have to include in the list the rect from their last position.

Answer (score 3):

When loading images, if you absolutely require transparency or other alpha values, use the Surface.convert_alpha() method. I have been using it for a game I've been programming, and it has been a huge increase in performance.
E.G: In your constructor, load your images using:

```
self.srcimage = pygame.image.load(imagepath).convert_alpha()
```

As far as I can tell, any transformations you do to the image retains the performance this method calls. E.G:

```
self.rotatedimage = pygame.transform.rotate(self.srcimage, angle).convert_alpha()
```

becomes redundant if you are using an image that has had `convert_alpha()` ran on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider for a well-performing Pygame application:

- Ensure that the image *Surface* has the same format as the display *Surface*. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)) to create a *Surface* that has the same pixel format. This improves performance when the image is `blit` on  the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` does not need to perform an implicit transformation. e.g.:

  ```py
  surf = pygame.image.load('my_image.png').convert_alpha()
  ```
- Do not load the images in the application loop. [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) is a very time-consuming operation because the image file must be loaded from the device and the image format must be decoded. Load the images once before the application loop, but use the images in the application loop.
- If you have a static game map that consists of tiles, you can buy performance by paying with memory usage. Create a large [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) with the complete map. [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the area which is currently visible on the screen:

  ```py
  game_map = pygame.Surface((tile_size * columns, tile_size * rows))
  for x in range(columns):
      for y in range(rows):
          tile_image = # image for this row and column
          game_map.blit(tile_image , (x * tile_size, y * tile_size))
  ```

  ```py
  while game:
      # [...]

      map_sub_rect = screen.get_rect(topleft = (camera_x, camera_y))
      screen.blit(game_map, (0, 0), map_sub_rect)

  # [...]
  ```
- If the text is static, the text does not need to be rendered in each frame. Create the text surface once at the beginning of the program or in the constructor of a class, and `blit` the text surface in each frame.
- If the text is dynamic, it cannot even be pre-rendered. However, the most time-consuming is to create the [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font)/[`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) object. At the very least, you should avoid creating the font in every frame.
  In a typical application you don't need all permutations of fonts and font sizes. You just need a couple of different `font` objects. Create a number of fonts at the beginning of the application and use them when rendering the text. For Instance. e.g.:

  ```py
  fontComic40  = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 40)
  fontComic180 = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 180)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Psyco (http://psyco.sourceforge.net/introduction.html). It often makes quite a bit of difference.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried Psyco and although it does speed up calculations and program execution quite a lot, what I am talking about is the rendering of graphics, unfortunately it does nothing to the number of frames pygame renders per second.Maybe its because pygame is a wrapper of SDL so maybe all the rendering is done in C? I have used SDL in C and even there it wasnt known for its speed. But it did manage to display 60-65 frames per sec.