# Pygame running super slow (~2 fps)

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame game runs super slowly, about 2 fps. You are supposed to be able to move around with WASD and always be centered in the screen. I know it has something to do with my tilemap and the way I do my math, but I can't pin it down.  Also, if there is a better way to keep the player in the center while moving the map behind it, I would love to know how to do that.

```
import pygame, sys, numpy
#create fps clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#
MAPHEIGHT = 80
MAPWIDTH = 80
TILESIZE =  40
TILESONSCREENW = 13
TILESONSCREENH = 13
#set screen size
SCREENH = TILESONSCREENH*TILESIZE
SCREENW = TILESONSCREENW*TILESIZE
#create character vars
circleRad = 40
circleSpeed = 4
#create circle pos vars
circleX = 250
circleY = 250
#create keyboard button vars
rightP = False
leftP = False
upP = False
downP = False
#
playerOnTileS = pygame.Surface((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))
#constants for the tilemap
GRASS = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
#tilemap
tilemap = [[GRASS for i in range(MAPHEIGHT)] for j in range(MAPWIDTH)]
#create window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENW, SCREENH))
#set window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Snowball Fight!")
#---------------------------------------------------
class Player:
    def __init__(self, playX, playY, size):
        self.playerX = playX
        self.playerY = playY
        self.size = size
        self.playerSurface = pygame.Surface((size, size))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.playerSurface, (19,135,67), (0,0,size, size))
#------------------------------------------------
    def update(self):
        playerOnTileS.blit(self.playerSurface, (self.playerX, self.playerY))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(playerOnTileS, (SCREENW/2-self.playerX-self.size ,SCREENH/2-self.playerY-self.size))
#game loop
myPlayer = Player(0,0,circleRad)
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #if the user closed the window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #close pygame
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                leftP = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rightP = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                upP = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                downP = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                leftP = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                rightP = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                upP = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                downP = False
    if leftP:
        myPlayer.move(-circleSpeed,0,True)
    if rightP:
        myPlayer.move(circleSpeed,0,True)
    if downP:
        myPlayer.move(0,circleSpeed,True)
    if upP:
        myPlayer.move(0,-circleSpeed,True)
    for row in range(len(tilemap)):
        for column in range(len(tilemap[row])):
            playerOnTileS.blit(tilemap[row][column],(column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))
    myPlayer.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: The code is not runnable since Player has no method named move. Please paste the full version for us to test

Comment: One potential problem has to do with the `playerOnTileS` surface you create. It's huge—3200W x 3200H. That size results in surface of 10,240,000 pixels (and each of those probably requires at least 3 or 4 bytes). If you want real help, you need to [edit] your question and add enough code so that others can run it and reproduce the problem. If possible, also include the `grass.png` image. If you can't add it directly to your question, then upload it to a website like [imgur](https://imgur.com) and then put a link to it in.

Comment: You don't need to draw the entire map, only the part that is visible on screen. It takes some (very minimal) math, but the speed-up ought to compensate for that – and then some.

Comment: The nested `for` loops near the end which do 80x80 = 6,400 `playerOnTileS.blit()`s between ***each*** `display.update()` are probably a major reason why it's so slooooooooooow...

Comment: The nested for loops are indeed the culprit, but once you correct that (by drawing only what is visible) you can further optimize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395923/any-way-to-speed-up-python-and-pygame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images/pygame.Surfaces should usually be converted with the [`pygame.Surface.convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` methods. The performance of unconverted surfaces is abysmal. When I convert the grass image, I get nearly 30 FPS.

The next problem is the nested `for` loop. Python's function call overhead is rather big, so it would be a good idea to blit all the tiles onto one large background surface before the main loop starts and then blit this background surface onto the `DISPLAYSURF` once per frame to clear it. With that change I get pygame's apparent maximum FPS, that means `clock.get_fps()` jumps between 2000 and 1666.666 FPS.

```
# Ahead of the while loop.
playerOnTileS = pygame.Surface((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))
for row in range(len(tilemap)):
    for column in range(len(tilemap[row])):
        playerOnTileS.blit(tilemap[row][column],(column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))
```

You have to change the `update` method (by the way, better call it `draw`) and blit the player surface onto the `DISPLAYSURF` instead.